# What is the purpose of the option name hack_file in the options table?

Tags: database, options

I was looking at the options table in a WordPress install and noticed an option name hack_file.  At first I thought the site was compromised and then realized it is a default option http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference .  I couldn't find much information regarding it.  What is it and its purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the codex says, it is legacy with probably no use in any modern version. I have been around wordpress since 2.0.4 and I don't remember it being used or referenced so my guess is that it is a really old legacy thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can see references to `hack_file` in WordPress core. Here's an example in WordPress 6.3 in `load.php` in the `wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins` function.

Here's the entire function (smaller snippet to follow):

```php
/**
 * Retrieve an array of active and valid plugin files.
 *
 * While upgrading or installing WordPress, no plugins are returned.
 *
 * The default directory is `wp-content/plugins`. To change the default
 * directory manually, define `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL`
 * in `wp-config.php`.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @return string[] Array of paths to plugin files relative to the plugins directory.
 */
function wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() {
    $plugins        = array();
    $active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );

    // Check for hacks file if the option is enabled.
    if ( get_option( 'hack_file' ) && file_exists( ABSPATH . 'my-hacks.php' ) ) {
        _deprecated_file( 'my-hacks.php', '1.5.0' );
        array_unshift( $plugins, ABSPATH . 'my-hacks.php' );
    }

    if ( empty( $active_plugins ) || wp_installing() ) {
        return $plugins;
    }

    $network_plugins = is_multisite() ? wp_get_active_network_plugins() : false;

    foreach ( $active_plugins as $plugin ) {
        if ( ! validate_file( $plugin )                     // $plugin must validate as file.
            && '.php' === substr( $plugin, -4 )             // $plugin must end with '.php'.
            && file_exists( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $plugin ) // $plugin must exist.
            // Not already included as a network plugin.
            && ( ! $network_plugins || ! in_array( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $plugin, $network_plugins, true ) )
            ) {
            $plugins[] = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $plugin;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Remove plugins from the list of active plugins when we're on an endpoint
     * that should be protected against WSODs and the plugin is paused.
     */
    if ( wp_is_recovery_mode() ) {
        $plugins = wp_skip_paused_plugins( $plugins );
    }

    return $plugins;
}
```

and here is the specific usage in that first if statement

```php
// Check for hacks file if the option is enabled.
if ( get_option( 'hack_file' ) && file_exists( ABSPATH . 'my-hacks.php' ) ) {
    _deprecated_file( 'my-hacks.php', '1.5.0' );
    array_unshift( $plugins, ABSPATH . 'my-hacks.php' );
}
```

It looks like you can set `hack_file` to `1` to enable it and then define `my-hacks.php` in the root of your WordPress installation (wherever `wp-config.php` lives). It'll then add it to the list of plugins to load.

So it seems it's a way to add some quick code to a WordPress install without formally creating a plugin or making changes to WordPress core files.

Comment: It looks like it's been deprecated since [WordPress 1.5.0, way back in aught-five](https://wordpress.org/documentation/wordpress-version/version-1-5/). I'd recommend against actually *using* it, though it's an interesting peek into how WP used to work.

Comment: I agree. I would not recommend actually using the option.